# How to format integers using DecimalFormat in Java?

Tags: java

How does the syntax of `DecimaFormat` work?
I'm trying to make `1234567890` --> `1-234-56789-0`.  So I tried `DecimalFormat("#-###-#####-#);`
But that's clearly wrong!

Comment: Could you show the complete code of what you tried doing?

Comment: `DecimalFormat d = new DeciamlFormat("#-###-#####-#);`

Comment: My input is any 10 digit number and I have to format it in that way

Comment: There is certainly more to your code than just that. That creates the format. But you have to do [something more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#format(long,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition)) to get a Stringish from it that you can then print. Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: All I have is that code segment and
`System.out.println(d.format(1234567890));`

Comment: Please write a complete program that tries to do what you are after.  Without this, we are just guessing at what you are trying to do and the data types involved.

Comment: A phone number is not really a number at all (you would never do arithmetic on phone numbers). A phone number is really a sequence of digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was so hopeful that my original answer would solve your problem, but.. no.  See this extract from `DecimalFormat`'s javadocs.

> The grouping separator is commonly used for thousands, but in some
>   countries it separates ten-thousands. The grouping size is a constant
>   number of digits between the grouping characters, such as 3 for
>   100,000,000 or 4 for 1,0000,0000. If you supply a pattern with
>   multiple grouping characters, the interval between the last one and
>   the end of the integer is the one that is used. So "#,##,###,####" ==
>   "######,####" == "##,####,####".

---

I had originally suggested using `DecimalFormatSymbols`. This will allow you to change the comma to a minus, but it won't allow for variable-length groups. So your requirements cannot be met using the built-in support for grouping. You need to build your own formatter or do it manually.